# Multiple random rows from small table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have following problem.

I have table Names which includes about 300 hundreds of random names. I need to generate from this table a set of RANDMLY selected names. It would be easy, just use order by dbms_random.random.. But I have to create about 1kk records and I cant do that.

I know how to randomize ONE record.. how to randomize whole table(those 300 values), but I dont know how to create set of 1kk records randomized from this table.

Would anyone help me with that? Thx!

Comment: What is 1kk? 1 million? What do you mean by creating 1kk random values from those 300 names?

Comment: wait, it would be just duplicates, why would you need that?

Comment: Sorry for not clear explonation bu I figured out the solution.
My full task was to create a table with:
- random date
- random name
- random surname
With one query. I had a separate tables with names and surnames.
At start I though I would need this table to random within. But later on I read about other possibility.. (LEVEL)
1 milion rows in 100s. Its good for me.
I need that for generating random data for testing application ;)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have duplicate rows, following is the possible way by which you can find out duplicate rows. Suppose there is a table Employee and it have two columns - id and name.

Data looks like:

```
id, name
1, Nikhil
1, Nikhil
2, Kunal 
2, Kunal
3, Rakesh
3, Rakesh
3, Rakesh
```

To find out duplicate queries, select query will be:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE GROUP BY ID, NAME;
```